# H2 console can't find entities on my laptop but it can on others

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

For a uni assignment we're starting to learn how to work with Spring boot, H2 console and JPA, so sorry in advance if I don't understand certain things I'm still very new at these subjects.

The problem is that we worked out how to load entities in to the h2 console on my group mate's laptop but when he pushed it to git and I try to run it on my laptop the h2 console does not see any of the entities.

I provided additional information down below, I hope someone will be able to help me. Thank you in advance!

Picture of map structure

[image: Picture of map structure]

Picture of console output
[image: Picture of console output]

Code:

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("businessLayer")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

User

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String department;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String password, String department) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User [id=%s, name=%s, department=%s]", id, name, department);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8081
```

application-dev.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>CoffeeBackEnd</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoffeeBackEnd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Is your application starting without errors?

Answer (score 0):

As it is configured now, the H2 database runs in memory. Everytime you stop the application, the content of the database is lost.

Also, there are no data.sql file in your src/main/resources, so the H2 database is not populated when you launch your application.

I guess that your mate should have the same problem as yours when the application is restarted.

Comment: But then how is it posible that the entities get loaded for him but not for me when we have the same project?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Do you see a difference in the console between your project and your mate project ? What happens when your mate takes a fresh copy of the project ? Did he commit push everything ?

Comment: He's looked at the console output and can't see anything different, also says he commited all the files. He tested it again in the evening yesterday and everything was working fine.